# Running gud-pdb with conda environment

Tags: python, emacs, conda, pdb, gdb-python

How can I run `pdb` from emacs on a file that is activated in a given `conda` environment.

I have setup `exec-path` and `PATH` to contain the current conda path, eg.

```
exec-path
("~/miniconda3/envs/sci/bin" ...)

(getenv "PATH")
"~/miniconda3/envs/sci/bin:..."
```

From within emacs,

```
(executable-find "python")
"~/miniconda3/envs/sci/bin/python
```

returns the proper python. `pdb` is located at "/usr/bin/pdb". However, if I run `pdb` on a file that is running in the `sci` conda environment, eg. its has `numpy`, etc. installed, `pdb` can't find those libraries:

test.py

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tst = np.linspace(1, 10, num=10)
print(tst)
```

<kbd>pdb</kbd> `./test.py`

```
Current directory is 
~/scratch/python/
> 
~/scratch/python/test.py(1)<module>()
-> import numpy as np
(Pdb) n
ImportError: 'No module named numpy'
> 
~/scratch/python/test.py(1)<module>()
-> import numpy as np
(Pdb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customizing `gud-pdb-command-name` to `python -m pdb` seems to work.

So, <kbd>pdb</kbd> `python -m pdb ./test.py`
runs in the correct environment.

Answer (score 0):

When using virtualenv or conda what I do is activate the env in a terminal and then launch emacs from that terminal. On a Mac:

```
$ conda activate hcpy
(hcpy)$ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

if you want to just have a terminal version of emacs add the argument -nw

then in emacs the command <kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> pdb

works fine for me.  The issue here is that there are often multiple python installs.  So it is not enough for emacs to find *a* python exe, emacs needs to find the python that has the libraries installed.

so for instance if I go:

```
$which python
```

I get:

```
/Users/jamesanderson/anaconda3/bin/python
```

but, if I go:

```
$source ./.py3dev/bin/activate
$which python
/Users/jamesanderson/code/python/camera/.py3dev/bin/python
```

so setup your virtual env with conda with the libraries you need.  When you are inside emacs and start a shell, and do the `which python` step.  The answer has to be the instance of python with the libraries installed.

Comment: that doesn't work on Ubuntu (kinda doubt it works on a Mac, did you try debugging an environment with a package not installed in your default env?), but it's also just too much extra baggage. Setting the conda env in emacs isn't a problem, you just need to manage the `exec-path` and `PATH` correctly when switching environments

Comment: on linux, just type `emacs` not the mac path (mac comes with an ancient emacs that is the default).

Comment: I'm on emacs 27, I don't have a system install, its build from source